# PHP check file extension

Tags: php

I have an upload script that I need to check the file extension, then run separate functions based on that file extension.  Does anybody know what code I should use?

```
if (FILE EXTENSION == ???)
{
FUNCTION1
}
else if
{
FUNCTION2
}
```

Answer (score 129, accepted):

`pathinfo` is what you're looking for

[PHP.net](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php)

```
$file_parts = pathinfo($filename);

switch($file_parts['extension'])
{
    case "jpg":
    break;

    case "exe":
    break;

    case "": // Handle file extension for files ending in '.'
    case NULL: // Handle no file extension
    break;
}
```

Comment: What's the case for no extension?   case NULL?  case ""?

Comment: Updated.  empty string `""` is for files then end with `.`. `NULL` is for no file extension.  You could break out the case statement, but for the example I just group them together.

Comment: `pathinfo($pathtofile, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)`

Answer (score 26):

```
$info = pathinfo($pathtofile);
if ($info["extension"] == "jpg") { .... }
```

Comment: I've used this code on a section of my website. However, when executing it along with `echo "$info"` it always returns the value Array. Why is this?

Comment: @user2910074 This question is OLD, and I'll have you see your code in order to provide with any help. I suggest that you'll post a question here on SO

Answer (score 8):

```
$file_parts = pathinfo($filename);

$file_parts['extension'];
$cool_extensions = Array('jpg','png');

if (in_array($file_parts['extension'], $cool_extensions)){
    FUNCTION1
} else {
    FUNCTION2
}
```

Comment: you might want to change the order of the 'needle' and the 'haystack' in `in_array`.

Answer (score 8):

For php `5.3+` you can use the `SplFileInfo()` class

```
$spl = new SplFileInfo($filename); 
print_r($spl->getExtension()); //gives extension
```

Also since you are checking extension for file uploads, I highly recommend using the mime type instead..

For php `5.3+` use the `finfo` class

```
$finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME);
print_r($finfo->buffer(file_get_contents($file name));
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$path = 'image.jpg';
echo substr(strrchr($path, "."), 1); //jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  $original_str="this . is . to . find";
  echo "<br/> Position: ". $pos=strrpos($original_str, ".");
  $len=strlen($original_str);
  if($pos >= 0)
  {
    echo "<br/> Extension: ".   substr($original_str,$pos+1,$len-$pos) ;
   }
```

Comment: @jurchiks `this . is . to . find` is absolutely a valid file name in most operating systems.

Answer (score 1):

```
$file = $_FILES["file"] ["tmp_name"]; 
$check_ext = strtolower(pathinfo($file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
if ($check_ext == "fileext") {
    //code
}
else { 
    //code
}
```