# TypeError: Value does not implement interface HTMLInputElement

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

I'am trying to post a form using  jQuery-ajax, and I'am getting this error on posting the form on click.
    `TypeError: Value does not implement interface HTMLInputElement`
here is my JavaScript code:

```
 $('document').ready(function () {
    $('#update').click(function () {
        jQuery.post("update_category", {
            c_id: c_id,
            c_name: c_name,
            c_description: c_description
        },

        function (data, textStatus) {
            if (data == 1) {
                $('#response').html("Thank You!!..We Will Get Back To You Soon..!!");
                $('#response').css('color', 'green');
            } else {
                $('#response').html("Some Error Occurred");
                $('#response').css('color', 'red');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

my form :

```
<div id="form">
    <form>
    <!-- PRONT DROP DOWN HERE !-->
        <input type="text" name="c_id" id="c_id" disabled="disble" placeholder="'.strtoupper($r['c_id']).'" value="'.strtoupper($r['c_id']).'" ></input>
        <input type="text" name="c_name" id="c_name" disabled="disble" placeholder="'.strtoupper($r['c_name']).'" value="'.strtoupper($r['c_name']).'"></input>
        <textarea rows="4" class="field span10" name="c_description" id="c_description"  disabled="disble" placeholder="Description">'.strtoupper($r['c_description']).'</textarea>

    </form> 
</div>
```

Comment: `.strtoupper($r['c_description']).` is it supposed to be server side code?!

Comment: Why do you use $('document') instead of $(document) ??

Comment: yaa .strtoupper($r['c_description']) i am aalso treating it s a server side and it is so...i am taking it on my form field, nd now posting it for update query

Comment: How do you get the values of c_id, c_name, c_description from the form

Answer (score 18):

This error can be generated if you send a jQuery object in an ajax request.
So in your situation, it's likely that one of `c_id`, `c_name`, or `c_description` is a jQuery object representing an input field rather than the `.val()` value of the input element.

Comment: That's an old answer, but I'd like to thank you. It shold be mark as the good answer.

Comment: just upvoted your answer as it solved my own problem...i was referencing the element not the value...+1 @milo-lamar

Answer (score 0):

Your form containing server side PHP code within HTML code.

PHP code should be written as below.

```
<input type="text" name="c_id" id="c_id" disabled="disble" placeholder="<?php echo strtoupper($r['c_id']) ; ?> " value="<?php echo strtoupper($r['c_id']) ; ?> " ></input>
```

Also check the below link for Jquery reference.

[Javascript: TypeError: Value does not implement interface FormData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16346714/javascript-typeerror-value-does-not-implement-interface-formdata)

Comment: friend i am using codeigniter and i hve given u the controller method code so no need to writei <?php

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
jQuery.post
```

use this

```
$.post
```

here full code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#update').click(function () {
        $.post("update_category", {
            c_id: c_id,
            c_name: c_name,
            c_description: c_description
        },

        function (data, textStatus) {
            if (data == 1) {
                $('#response').html("Thank You!!..We Will Get Back To You Soon..!!");
                $('#response').css('color', 'green');
            } else {
                $('#response').html("Some Error Occurred");
                $('#response').css('color', 'red');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Hope it will help

Comment: @user2488557 is c_id etc variable defined before use?

Answer (score 0):

Check the below code. span or div with id="response" is missing in your code  and replace jquery.post by $.post. Give the file name update_category with the extension

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $('document').ready(function(){
            var c_id = '1', c_name = 'test', c_description = 'testing';
            $('#update').click(function(){
                $.post("update_category.php", {
                    c_id:c_id,
                    c_name: c_name,
                    c_description: c_description                                       
                    }, function(data){
                        if(data == 1){
                            $('#response').html("Thank You!!..We Will Get Back To You Soon..!!");
                            $('#response').css('color','green');
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $('#response').html("Some Error Occurred");
                            $('#response').css('color','red');
                        }
                });
            });
        });
        </script>
    </head>
<body>
    <div id="form">
        <form>
            <!-- PRONT DROP DOWN HERE !-->
            <input type="text" name="c_id" id="c_id" placeholder="" value="" />
            <input type="text" name="c_name" id="c_name" placeholder="" value="" />
            <textarea rows="4" class="field span10" name="c_description" id="c_description"  placeholder="Description"></textarea>
            <input type="button" id="update" value="Update" />
            <span id="response"></span> <!-- This is missing in your form -->
        </form> 
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i am using codeigniter so no need of .php extension,just give the method name of controller... and i hv tried with  $.post still not getting vlue post to controller

Comment: How do you get the values of c_id, c_name, c_description from the form

Answer (score 0):

Try to use value inside variables

```
$('document').ready(function () {
$('#update').click(function () {
    jQuery.post("update_category", {
        c_id: c_id.val(),
        c_name: c_name.val(),
        c_description: c_description.val()
  },
    function (data, textStatus) {
        if (data == 1) {
            $('#response').html("Thank You!!..We Will Get Back To You Soon..!!");
            $('#response').css('color', 'green');
        } else {
            $('#response').html("Some Error Occurred");
            $('#response').css('color', 'red');
        }
    });
});
```