# how to upload the images using ajax in button on click listener in php without form submit

Tags: php, ajax

**html:**

```
<input type="file" onChange="readURL(this,'#Image2N');"  name="txtImage2N" id="txtImage2N" value="<?php echo $Image2N;?>">
```

**javascript**

```
$('#txtImage2N').on("change", function() {

    var data = new FormData();
    $.ajax({
           url: 'load.php', 
           type: 'POST',
           contentType: false,
           data: data,
           processData: false,
           cache: false
    })
 });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send image to PHP file using Ajax?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21164365/how-to-send-image-to-php-file-using-ajax)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15327377/4229270

Comment: Possible duplicate of [upload multiple images with jquery ajax and process them with php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15259632/upload-multiple-images-with-jquery-ajax-and-process-them-with-php)