# jQuery file upload fails using several inputs with FormData ajax()

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

*EDIT*
I'm trying to send several input values trough jQuery / ajax() with a file in it and ajax() doesn't seems to support both in the same time. I've found that FormData would do the trick.
[Using jQuery ajax to upload file and form data with formData()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16743045/using-jquery-ajax-to-upload-file-and-form-data-with-formdata)
http://www.thefourtheye.in/2013/10/file-upload-with-jquery-and-ajax.html

*UPDATE*
I don't have any errors anymore but the file is not uploaded properly into the MySQL DB/LongBlob columb. It seems to be properly received now in the PHP file.

html

```
    <input type=hidden name=catselid id=catselid value=".$id.">
    <input name=city id=city>
    <input name=country id=country>
    <input type=file name=picture id=picture >
    <input name=update value=update type=submit class=update id=update  />
```

javascript

```
    $(".update").click(function(){

        $.ajax({
            url: 'catsel_change.php',
            type: 'POST',
            contentType:false,
            processData: false,
            data: function(){
                var data = new FormData();
                data.append('picture',$('#picture').get(0).files[0]);
                data.append('city' , $('#cityname').val());
                data.append('country', $('#country').val());
                data.append('id', $('#catselid').val());
                return data;
            }(),
                success: function(result) {
                alert(result);
                },
            error: function(xhr, result, errorThrown){
                alert('Request failed.');
            }
            });

    });
```

php

```
if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['picture']['tmp_name'])){
    $picture =addslashes (file_get_contents($_FILES['picture']['tmp_name']));
...
}
```

FYI, I'm using jQuery 1.9.1
comments/suggestions are welcome
regards

Comment: Try looking at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery :)

Comment: http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#ajaxSubmit an ajax/iframe method of sending a form with file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got it finally. Just a stupid messy "," left behind in the php file. Now all works properly. 
Thanks for help!

Answer (score -2):

There is no way of sending file to the server through a true ajax call. i recommend you to put your form in a hidden iframe and submit it from the parent.

Comment: Of course there _are_ ways, using the HTML5 File API – but you have to implement it yourself.