# PHP directory player error when choosing comedy but not action

Tags: php, forms, directory, movie, video-player

I'm making a code, that gets sent a list of directories. It searches the directorys for video files. Determines if it is an MP4 or an avi and echos a code. For some reason I have it working when I select " action" folder... but it doesn't work when it is set on comedy folder. Both folders I have created, with a video inside. Action folder works but comedy does not?.

Here is form code:

```
<form name="contact" method="POST" action="Player.php" >
    <select name="taskOption">
        <option value="action">action</option>
        <option value="comedy">comedy</option>
    </select>
    <input id="submitBtn" type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">&nbsp;<input type="reset" name="Reset" value="Reset">
</form>
```

And here is the uber long player...

```
<?php
// picks up info from DirMap
$dir = $_POST['taskOption'];
echo("<ul>");
$dir_handle = opendir("./$dir/");
while ($file = readdir($dir_handle)) {
    $rest = "./$dir/$file";
    /* What needs to be done is it needs to distinguish if a file is a avi. 
    If it is , echo the avi player code , else echo correct player .. example 
    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7563658/php-check-file-extension */
    $info = pathinfo($file);
    if ($info["extension"] == "avi") {
        echo("<br/> <li>");
        echo("<li><div><a name=\"$file\">");
        echo("<h2><$file is a avi file</h2>");
        echo("<object id=\"MediaPlayer1\" CLASSID=\"CLSID:22d6f312-b0f6-11d0-94ab-0080c74c7e95\" codebase=\"http://activex.microsoft.com/activex/controls/mplayer/en/nsmp2inf.cab#Version=5,1,52,701\" ");
        echo("standby=\"Loading Microsoft Windows® Media Player components...\" type=\"application/x-oleobject\" width=\"280\" height=\"256\ poster=\"lightning.jpg\">");
        echo("<param name=\"fileName\" value=\"$rest\">");
        echo("<param name=\"animationatStart\" value=\"false\">");
        echo("<param name=\"transparentatStart\" value=\"false\">");
        echo("<param name=\"autoStart\" value=\"false\">");
        echo("<param name=\"showControls\" value=\"true\">");
        echo("<param name=\"Volume\" value=\"-450\">");
        echo("<embed type=\"application/x-mplayer2\" pluginspage=\"http://www.microsoft.com/Windows/MediaPlayer/\" src=\"$rest\" name=\"MediaPlayer1\" width=280 height=256 autostart=0 showcontrols=1 volume=-450>");
        echo("</object>");
        echo("<br/>");
        //do stuff with $file
        echo("<h2><a href=\"$rest\">$file is a avi file</a></h2>");
        echo("<a href=\"#top\">Back to top of Page</a><hr></div></li><br/><br/>"); 
        echo("<div class=\"banner\"><script src=\"banner.js\" ></script></div>");
    } else if ($info["extension"] == "mp4") { 
        echo("<br><br><div><a name=\"$file\"></a>");
        echo("<li>");
        echo("<h2>$file is a mp4 file</h2>");
        echo("<video source src=\"$rest\" type=\"video/mp4\" height=\"350\" width=\"400\" controls=\"controls\" poster=\"lightning.png\" preload=\"none\" \" tabindex=\"0\" allowfullscreen=\"true\">");
        echo(" </video> ");
        echo("<h2><a href=\"$rest\">$file is a mp4 file</a></h2>");
        echo("<a href=\"#top\">Back  to top of Page</a></div></li><br/><br/><hr>");
        echo("<div class=\"banner\"><script src=\"banner.js\" ></script></div>"); 
    }//end of else
}
echo("</ul>");
?>
```

Why does it throw an error if I choose comedy but not action?

Answer (score 0):

Something like

end(explode(".", $file));

Would return the extension a lot easier