# best secured way to guess file extension

Tags: php, security, upload

I'm looking for the most secure way to determine the extension of a file that a user has sent to my server. 
I know I should not trust the image files sent by forms. 
I would start to guess it from my tmp file before moving it to my upload dir.

thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP check file extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7563658/php-check-file-extension)

Comment: There is no definitive way to get the extension, but using the mime-type might be your best bet, if `SplFileInfo::getExtension` proves to be unreliable

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `pathinfo` function for this like:

```
$file = "a.jpg";
var_dump(pathinfo($file));
```

There will be an extension key.
But i suggest you to not just validate the extension of the file, but mime type also!

Comment: The extension returned by pathinfo on a tmp file is 'tmp', this is not what i need...

Comment: @rudak You use the function on the file name, not the temporary file name.

Comment: the name can be false , i think this is not very secure

Comment: @rudak Like lolka_bolka said. You can use `$_FILES['thefile']['type']` to check its mime type.

Comment: @rudak: please read my note below the code: " to not just validate the extension of the file, **but mime type also**"

Comment: yes, see here http://php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php and here http://php.net/manual/en/function.image-type-to-mime-type.php and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486329/how-can-i-only-allow-certain-filetypes-on-upload-in-php

Answer (score 0):

I found this method :

```
public static function is_image($image_path)
{
    if (!$f = fopen($image_path, 'rb')) {
        return false;
    }

    $data = fread($f, 8);
    fclose($f);

    $unpacked = unpack("H12", $data);
    if (array_pop($unpacked) == '474946383961' || array_pop($unpacked) == '474946383761')
        return "gif";
    $unpacked = unpack("H4", $data);
    if (array_pop($unpacked) == 'ffd8')
        return "jpg";
    $unpacked = unpack("H16", $data);
    if (array_pop($unpacked) == '89504e470d0a1a0a')
        return "png";

    return false;
}
```

What do you think about it ?
thx

Comment: So I just need to dump 8 arbitrary bytes then add `<?php eval(gzinflate(base64_decode($malware)));` and you're owned.