# How Do I Check If a String of Text Ends With '.PDF' Using PHP?

Tags: php, string, pdf

I have a string of text called `doc/document1.pdf`. Is there PHP code I can use that will allow me to check if the last 4 characters are equal to '.pdf'?

I am looking for code that looks like this:

```
<?php if($stringoftext_lastfourcharacters == '.pdf') {

echo "This is a PDF";

}

?>
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual-lookup.php?pattern=EN%2Fref.strings.php&lang=en&scope=404quickref

Comment: if you want to know the file type. **Don't** use the extension use the mime type: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.fileinfo.php

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php

Comment: @AbraCadaver yeah, saw this one too http://stackoverflow.com/a/7563688/ - more than one way to hit a barn door ;-) question here could be a dupe of.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`substr()`](http://php.net/substr) -

```
if(substr($myString, -4) == '.pdf')....
```

Or use [`pathinfo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) -

```
$info = pathinfo($myString);
if ($info["extension"] == "pdf") ....
```

You can also use [`explode()`](http://php.net/explode) -

```
$myStringParts = explode('.', $myString);
if($myString[count($myStringParts) - 1] == 'pdf')....
```

Comment: You could wrap the substr in `strtolower()` in order to return true if the file is upper case.

Answer (score 3):

Regex way

```
$reg="/\.pdf$/i";
$text= "doc/document1.pdf";
if(preg_match($reg,$text, $output_array)) { echo "This is a pdf";}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if(substr($str,strlen($str)-3)==="pdf") {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `str_ends_with`. Example:

`if(str_ends_with($str, "pdf")) {...}`