# How to check a file extension from file path?

Tags: php, file

I am creating a portal in which i am uploading multiple file, when iam retrieving them i am unable to know what types of file they are(images,audio and video) is there any way to find out??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP check file extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7563658/php-check-file-extension)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get(extract) a file extension in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173868/how-to-getextract-a-file-extension-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

**Try This:**

```
$extension = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

Php Doc: [pathinfo()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php)

For more: [SplFileInfo::getExtension](http://php.net/manual/en/splfileinfo.getextension.php)